# How to active/onfocus the dashboard UI tabs from clicking submenu of the main menubar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a menu "Tasks" with submenus name "Assigned", "UnAssigned" and "Summary" in the main menu bar.

In the below dashboard page of the menu, i have the UI tabs named "Assigned", "UnAssigned", Reports, Approved, Etc...

My question is, if i click the submenu "UnAssigned" the UI tab "UnAssigned" need to get active and shows its contents and if i click the submenu "Assigned" the UI tab "Assigned"  get active and shows its contents.

My html code for main menu...

```
     <ul>
      <?php
      if ($usergroup!='DigitizationArtist' && $usergroup!='GraphicArtist')
      { echo '<li><span onclick="UnAssigned()"><a href="">UnAssigned</a></span></li>';}
      ?>
      <li><span onclick="Assigned()"><a href="">Assigned</a></span></li>
      <li><span onclick="Completed()"><a href="#">Completed</a></span></li>
      <li><span onclick="Approved()"><a href="#">Approved</a></span></li>
    </ul>
```

my jquery for active assigned and unassigned..

```
 <script>
  $(function (Assigned)
  {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
  });
 </script>
 <script>
  $(function (UnAssigned)
  {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 0 });
  });
 </script>
```

my html coding for UI tabs...

```
    <div id="tabs" class="uitabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tab-1">Un Assigned</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tab-2">Assigned</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="tab-3">Summary</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
```

Please advise... what is wrong in my jquery coding...(i am new to jquery)

Otherwise help me with other javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded in cloud.

Check [this](http://www.bootply.com/X5mNP3XuZR)

Comment: Ashok it is working fine. It is anyways to do the same things for UI tabs. Since i have the Tabs in other pages.